# Creating a stored procedure to match the input parameters with some values from a request and return back some values on output params

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

here's my code

here's how I defined my procedure with the input and output params and the `select` I want to make to match the values from a request to input params and if there's a match to data from the table then get the output values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WS_STOCK_RESERVATION_CATEGORY 
 (
  P_CONTEXT IN VARCHAR2,
  P_SERIAL_FLAG IN VARCHAR2,
  P_RESERVATION_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
  P_SERIAL_NUMBER IN NUMBER ,
  P_DEALER_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
  P_WAREHOUSE_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
  P_ACTION IN VARCHAR2,
  P_ORDER_ID IN VARCHAR2,
  P_OA_ID IN VARCHAR2,
  P_COMPONENT_ID IN VARCHAR2,
  P_RESERVATION_ID IN NUMBER,
  ITEM_CODE OUT VARCHAR2,
  RESERVATION_ID OUT NUMBER,
  RETURN_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2
) AS 
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM TEST362
    WHERE P_CONTEXT = P_CONTEXT 
    AND P_SERIAL_FLAG = P_SERIAL_FLAG
    AND P_RESERVATION_CODE = P_RESERVATION_CODE
    AND P_SERIAL_NUMBER = P_SERIAL_NUMBER
    AND P_DEALER_CODE =P_DEALER_CODE
    AND P_WAREHOUSE_CODE = P_WAREHOUSE_CODE
    AND P_ACTION = P_ACTION
    AND P_ORDER_ID = P_ORDER_ID
    AND P_OA_ID = P_OA_ID
    AND P_COMPONENT_ID = P_COMPONENT_ID
    AND P_RESERVATION_ID = P_RESERVATION_ID
    
    ITEM_CODE := 'CiprianItemCode';
    RESERVATION_ID := 2000;
    RETURN_MESSAGE := 'SperSaMeargaWS362';
 
END WS_STOCK_RESERVATION_CATEGORY;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: im using oracle, with sql developer

Comment: I believe your query is missing a [INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm). Or did I miss something?

Comment: I Agree with @Abra,  `into` missed, and good practice says you should use `exception` at least for to cases `too_many_rows` and `no_data_found`.